# Need to infer second generic type from first. 'SequenceItem' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const SORT_VALUES = {
    a: -1,
    b: 1,
} as const
type sortWrapperReturn = -1 | 1 | 0
    export const sortWrapper = <T extends string, SequenceItem = T>({
    a,
    b,
    sequence,
}: {
    a: T
    b: T
    sequence?: SequenceItem[]
}): sortWrapperReturn => {
    if (a === b) return 0

    if (sequence) {
        const aIndex = sequence.indexOf(a)
        const bIndex = sequence.indexOf(b)

        if (aIndex === -1) return SORT_VALUES.b
        if (bIndex === -1) return SORT_VALUES.a

        if (aIndex > bIndex) return SORT_VALUES.b
        if (aIndex < bIndex) return SORT_VALUES.a
    }


    return 0
}
```

I need to inherit the second generic type from the first so that the type from 'a' and 'b' parameters was inferred to 'sequence' parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` should be assignable to `SequenceItem`.

`SequenceItem = T` does not mean that `T` is assignable to `SequenceItem`. In order to fix it, you need to assure TypeScript that `sequence` argument is a set of `T`. Consider this example:

```js
const SORT_VALUES = {
    a: -1,
    b: 1,
} as const

type sortWrapperReturn = -1 | 1 | 0

export const sortWrapper = <T extends string>({
    a,
    b,
    sequence,
}: {
    a: T
    b: T
    sequence?: T[]
}): sortWrapperReturn => {
    if (a === b) return 0

    if (sequence) {
        const aIndex = sequence.indexOf(a)
        const bIndex = sequence.indexOf(b)

        if (aIndex === -1) return SORT_VALUES.b
        if (bIndex === -1) return SORT_VALUES.a

        if (aIndex > bIndex) return SORT_VALUES.b
        if (aIndex < bIndex) return SORT_VALUES.a
    }


    return 0
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N71BGW)

Or, you can use `intersection` with `T[]`:

```js
export const sortWrapper = <T extends string, Sequence = T>({
    a,
    b,
    sequence,
}: {
    a: T
    b: T
    sequence?: Sequence[] & T[] // < ---- change
}): sortWrapperReturn => {
    // ... code
}

sortWrapper({ a: 'a', b: 'b', sequence: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nrn6oN)